# ESP32 arduino with PlatformIO Serial0.printf("%d %d \n",x,x) Loss the second data

Tags: arduino, printf, esp32, arduino-esp32

I used PlatformIO with arduino-framework = arduino to develop the ESP32 code, and use Serial.printf for Debug, like this:

```cpp
  int64_t test_val = 12345;
  Serial0.printf("ADC millivolts value = %d , tim:%d \n",analogVolts,test_val);
```

I found that the second %d is not output properly，the result like this（Actually tim=12345) :

```
ADC millivolts value = 31 , tim:3
```

so,I did some tests using the code below：

```cpp
  int analogVolts = analogReadMilliVolts(1);
  int64_t test_val = 12345;
  Serial0.printf("ADC millivolts value = %d , tim:%d \n",analogVolts,test_val);
  Serial0.printf("Test-d:%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d \n",
                  test_val,test_val,test_val,test_val,
                  test_val,test_val,test_val,test_val);
  Serial0.printf("Test-ld:%ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld \n \n",
                  test_val,test_val,test_val,test_val,
                  test_val,test_val,test_val,test_val);
```

The result of running these tests-code is:

```
ADC millivolts value = 32 , tim:3 
Test-d:12345, 0, 12345, 0, 12345, 0, 12345, 0 
Test-ld:12345, 0, 12345, 0, 12345, 0, 12345, 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjsmn.png)

**Some other information：**

```
Visual Studio Code: V1.79.0
PlatformIO：  Core 6.1.13·Home 3.4.4
Platforms： Espressif 32 v6.5.0
```

platformio.ini：

```
[env:adafruit_feather_esp32s3]
platform = espressif32
board = adafruit_feather_esp32s3
framework = arduino
board_build.f_cpu = 240000000L
board_build.f_flash = 80000000L
upload_speed = 921600
monitor_speed=921600
lib_deps = adafruit/Adafruit NeoPixel@^1.12.0
```

and there is the function anbout `size_t Print::printf(const char *format, ...)`  in file `C:\Users\UserName\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif32\cores\esp32\Print.cpp` line 47 :

```cpp
size_t Print::printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    char loc_buf[64];
    char * temp = loc_buf;
    va_list arg;
    va_list copy;
    va_start(arg, format);
    va_copy(copy, arg);
    int len = vsnprintf(temp, sizeof(loc_buf), format, copy);
    va_end(copy);
    if(len < 0) {
        va_end(arg);
        return 0;
    }
    if(len >= (int)sizeof(loc_buf)){  // comparation of same sign type for the compiler
        temp = (char*) malloc(len+1);
        if(temp == NULL) {
            va_end(arg);
            return 0;
        }
        len = vsnprintf(temp, len+1, format, arg);
    }
    va_end(arg);
    len = write((uint8_t*)temp, len);
    if(temp != loc_buf){
        free(temp);
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with PlatformIO, it has to do with c-string formatter specifier. Use `%lld` specifier for data type of `int64_t` and `long long`, and `%llu` for `uint64_t` and `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you've used the wrong [length specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). `%d` expects to print data of type `int` which is 32 bits long on ESP32.

Your data type is `int64_t` which is 64 bits long and gets formatted incorrectly. Since on ESP32 (and on very many other platforms) `int64_t` is an alias to `long long int` then the *quick* solution is to use its length specifier `lld` instead of `d`:

```cpp
  int64_t test_val = 12345;
  Serial0.printf("ADC millivolts value = %d , tim:%lld \n",analogVolts,test_val);
```

Note that standard libraries define [macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants) that automatically replace the correct length for `int64_t` (and other types with defined length like `int32_t`, `int16_t`, `int8_t`) on the target platform. So the *portable* (and quite ugly-looking) solution would be to use length specifier `PRId64`:

```cpp
  int64_t test_val = 12345;
  Serial0.printf("ADC millivolts value = %d , tim:%" PRId64 " \n",analogVolts,test_val);
```